# Diffie-Hellman cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#

I am keep having this problem.

> The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.
>
> Exception Details: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.

The below is the code.  This codes are failed on Windows XP Pro SP3 and Windows 2003 Server with 3.5 framework installed on it.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System"%>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web"%>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography"%>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">

</head>

<body>

  <%

    //http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2007/01/22/elliptic-curve-diffie-hellman.aspx

    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488021.aspx is about 200-millisecond wait.

    ECDiffieHellmanCng alice = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();

    alice.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;

    alice.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;

    ECDiffieHellmanCng bob = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();

    bob.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;

    bob.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;

    byte[] bobKey = bob.DeriveKeyMaterial(alice.PublicKey);

    byte[] aliceKey = alice.DeriveKeyMaterial(bob.PublicKey);

    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

    aes.Key = aliceKey;

    

     %>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng.aspx) says the class is supported on the following OSes:

- Windows 7
- Windows Vista SP1 or later
- Windows XP SP3
- Windows Server 2008
  (Server Core Role not supported)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core
  Role not supported)

Comment: I tried it on Windows XP SP3 with .NET 3.5 SP1 and I get the same error message.

Comment: I actually had the exact same problem for some other method. The documentation says that it is compatible with my OS, yet I get this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Based on reading other Microsoft documentation, my own experiments, and the questioner's, I'm convinced that the MSDN docs are in error and that Elliptic Curve DH is only supported on Windows Vista and higher. ECDH is only supported by Windows CNG, which in turn is only available on Vista and higher. I would love to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to a differences in operating systems. The code you are trying to run may only work in certain Windows OS's, or on only 64-bit or only 32-bit computers. Do you have documentation for this algorithm>?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng.aspx
The document said 
Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role not supported)
The .NET Framework does not support all versions of every platform. For a list of the supported versions, see .NET Framework System Requirements. 
Supported in: 4, 3.5